# AWS IoT CONNECTION_LOST

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot, aws-iot

I am working on a AWS IoT python script using [aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2 library](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-python-v2) to publish a message and receive a reply on a separate topics. I am able to publish the message to the thing, but not able to receive reply as the connection breaks as soon as the payload is pushed and I get an lifecycle event **"disconnectReason": "CONNECTION_LOST"**

So the current flow of lifecycle events is **Connected -> Subscribed -> Disconnected (Connection_Lost)** . I am not able to figure out the reason this disconnect, connection lost event. Any help is appreciated. Adding below the script used and disconnect event

```
from awscrt import io, mqtt, auth, http
from awsiot import mqtt_connection_builder
import sys
import threading
import time
import json
import os

target_ep = "xx"
cert_filepath = "xx-certificate.pem.crt"
private_key_filepath = "xx-private.pem.key"
ca_filepath = "xx/AmazonRootCA1.pem"

thing_name = "Tee_123_Laser"
pub_topic = "M5_1_Laser_I"
sub_topic = "M5_1_Reply_I"

# Callback when connection is accidentally lost.
def on_connection_interrupted(connection, error, **kwargs):
    print("Connection interrupted. error: {}".format(error))

# Callback when an interrupted connection is re-established.
def on_connection_resumed(connection, return_code, session_present, **kwargs):
    print("Connection resumed. return_code: {} session_present: {}".format(return_code, session_present))

    if return_code == mqtt.ConnectReturnCode.ACCEPTED and not session_present:
        print("Session did not persist. Resubscribing to existing topics...")
        resubscribe_future, _ = connection.resubscribe_existing_topics()

        # Cannot synchronously wait for resubscribe result because we're on the connection's event-loop thread,
        # evaluate result with a callback instead.
        resubscribe_future.add_done_callback(on_resubscribe_complete)

def on_resubscribe_complete(resubscribe_future):
    resubscribe_results = resubscribe_future.result()
    print("Resubscribe results: {}".format(resubscribe_results))

    for topic, qos in resubscribe_results['topics']:
        if qos is None:
            sys.exit("Server rejected resubscribe to topic: {}".format(topic))

# Callback when the subscribed topic receives a message
def on_message_received(topic, payload, dup, qos, retain, **kwargs):
    print("Received message from topic '{}': {}".format(topic, payload))

# Spin up resources
event_loop_group = io.EventLoopGroup(1)
host_resolver = io.DefaultHostResolver(event_loop_group)
client_bootstrap = io.ClientBootstrap(event_loop_group, host_resolver)

proxy_options = None

mqtt_connection = mqtt_connection_builder.mtls_from_path(
    endpoint=target_ep,
    port=8883,
    cert_filepath=cert_filepath,
    pri_key_filepath=private_key_filepath,
    client_bootstrap=client_bootstrap,
    ca_filepath=ca_filepath,
    on_connection_interrupted=on_connection_interrupted,
    on_connection_resumed=on_connection_resumed,
    client_id=thing_name,
    clean_session=False,
    keep_alive_secs=300,
    http_proxy_options=proxy_options,
)

print("Connecting to {} with client ID '{}'...".format(
    target_ep, thing_name))
connect_future = mqtt_connection.connect()
connect_future.result()
print("Connected!")

# Subscribe
print("Subscribing to topic " + sub_topic)
subscribe_future, packet_id = mqtt_connection.subscribe(
    topic=sub_topic,
    qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE,
    callback=on_message_received,
)

laser_payload = {
    "TransactionType": "point",
    "Hole": 1,
    "Tee": 1,
    "Laser": {
        "Mode": 1,
        "LX": 20,
        "LY": 0,
        "LZ": 0,
        "LH": 192,
        "LXA": 0,
        "LYA": 0
    },
    "Ball": {
        "BX": 60,
        "BY": 60,
        "BZ": 0
    }
}

print("QOS {}".format(mqtt.QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE))
message_json = json.dumps(laser_payload)
print(message_json)

mqtt_connection.publish(
    topic=pub_topic,
    payload=message_json,
    qos=mqtt.QoS.AT_MOST_ONCE,
)
```

Disconnect event :

```
{
  "clientId": "Tee_123_Laser",
  "timestamp": 1691312864042,
  "eventType": "disconnected",
  "clientInitiatedDisconnect": false,
  "sessionIdentifier": "58bae8d6-1232-4198-a57e-2c8c209cd308",
  "principalIdentifier": "75c3e1e6750a81346fc758b853921bf07abff928b90d9b2b1bba4ed78f1c8ac1",
  "disconnectReason": "CONNECTION_LOST",
  "versionNumber": 6
}
```

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/life-cycle-events.html#:~:text=Yes.-,CONNECTION_LOST,-The%20client%2Dserver, "The client-server connection is cut off. This can happen during a period of high network latency or when the internet connection is lost.", When this happend you could try to re-connect, the reason for this disconnect is not in your code.

Comment: @Luuk I already read this in the documentation, but not sure if internet is the issue. Can you suggest any mechanism to try re-connect without creating duplicate connections ?

Comment: When "CONNECTION_LOST" you do no longer have a connection, so you cannot get a duplicate connection ?

Comment: @Luuk Agreed ! And I am not getting duplicate client error now. Can you help me with ways to re-connect or keep this connection live ?

Comment: sorry, not enough experience with AWS/IOT, but there is enough info like: [AutoReconect](http://aws-iot-device-sdk-embedded-c-docs.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/AutoReconnect.html) and [Does auto reconnect works same as before?](https://github.com/aws/aws-iot-device-sdk-java-v2/issues/108)